# Drupal 7 Taxonomy: Find TID by custom field value

Tags: drupal, field, taxonomy

// Application

Drupal 7

// Problem Background

My website imports product data from a CSV file. I have a module that parses the file and creates appropriate nodes. In the CSV file, product category is given by category ID, which are different than Taxonomy Term IDs I have for the product categories in Drupal. I have created a custom field in my Taxonomy Vocabulary ("category_id") to link Drupal categories to imported category IDs.

When creating a node during import, I need "tid" (Taxonomy Term ID) to assign a node to a Taxonomy Term.

// The Question

How can I find Taxonomy Term ID ("tid"), knowing the value of a custom Taxonomy field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom taxonomy field ("category_id") creates a table `field_data_field_category_id` which should have an `entity_id` column/field which is your tid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have command line Drush access, you could do:

```
drush php-eval '$tax=taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load("main_site_structure");echo $tax->vid;'
```